# Filter ArrayList multiple times in Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist, filter

I need to filter an ArrayList each time that user input a string in a textbox or/and click a button to add boolean attribute to filters.

```
public class ItemULD {
    private int idULD;
    private String contour;
    private String numULD;
    private boolean withNet;
}
```

And I tried with this method to filter the string in textbox

```
List<Integer> ids = grupoChip.getCheckedChipIds();
 for (Integer id : ids) {
   Chip chip = grupoChip.findViewById(id);
    ArrayList<ItemULD> arrayFiltered; = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ItemULD uld : arrayULD) {
      String num = String.valueOf(uld.getNumULD());
       if (num.contains(chip.getText()) || uld.getContour().contains(chip.getText())) {
        if (!arrayFiltered.contains(uld))
         arrayFiltered.add(uld);
       }
    }

 //Method to filter ULD's with net
    public static List<ItemULD> filters(List<ItemULD> allULD, boolean net){
            List<ItemULD> list = new ArrayList<>();
            for (ItemULD uld : allULD) {
                if (!net || uld.iswithNet()) {
                    list.add(uld);
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

The problem is when I try to add a new filter on the filtered results that didn't works..
E.G.
I have this.

```
idULD:1,
contour:EK, 
numULD: 123456,
withNet:1

idULD:2,
contour:AF, 
numULD: 652466,
withNet:0

idULD:3,
contour:AF, 
numULD: 123663,
withNet:0
```

If I put on my seach textbox `123` I see 2 results id1 & id3 this is ok, but when I add `AF` I see two AF not only the match `AF + 123` that would be the id3.

On the other hand, if I click the option to filter by attribute `withNet` I see all the results. I guess this is caused because I'm creating a new array in the method to return but, how I could do it?

**EDIT**

I use a ChipGroup to add Chip elements with the string that user write in a textbox. Then I iterate the ChipGroud to get the text of every Chip.
So if the user write "123" + Enter a new Chip is added to the group

Comment: Can you clarify if you have a single search text box (in total) or if you multiple search text boxes? In which variable is the text box stored, is it `chip`? If yes, it is unclear to me why the code would work for multiple criteria within the same text box (i.e. AF + 123), since you check if the complete text is contained: `num.contains(chip.getText()) || uld.getContour().contains(chip.getText())`

Comment: I edited the question to add more info, I use a GroupChip to add a new chip when user write something in one textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An extendable way of solving this is creating an interface `Filter`,
something like this:

```java
interface Filter{
  // This method checks if the filter is applied for the provided itemText.
  // For example, if the filter is a numULD filter, it returns true 
  // iff the itemText is a number. 
  boolean isApplicableTo(String itemText);

  // This method applies the filter. It returns true if the resulting list
  // shall contain the item, and false if the item shall not appear in the
  // list. For example, for the contour filter, the return value of the method is 
  // item.getContour().contains(itemText)
  boolean applyTo(ItemULD item, String itemText); 
}
```

Now create three classes implementing this interface, one for `contour`, one for `numULD`, and one for `withNet`. Create instances of these classes and put them in a collection. Iterate over the collection and check if the filter is applicable and if yes, apply the filter. And then perform an and operation (`&&`) on the result, starting with a variable `boolean result = true;`

If you've done that, you could even move this method to its own class `Filters`that takes several filters as arguments and returns the filtered result list.

**EDIT**: Here's a code example.

This is a test class that checks that the filter works correctly:

```java
class FiltersTest {

    @Test
    void testsFilters() {
        Filter contourFilter = new ContourFilter();
        Filter numFilter = new NumFilter();
        Filters filters = new Filters(contourFilter, numFilter);
        
        ItemULD item1 = new ItemULD(1, "EK", "123456", true);
        ItemULD item2 = new ItemULD(2, "AF", "652466", false);
        ItemULD item3 = new ItemULD(3, "AF", "123663", false);
        List<ItemULD> items = Arrays.asList(item1, item2, item3);
        
        List<Chip> chips = Arrays.asList(new Chip("AF"), new Chip("123"));
        
        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(item3), filters.applyToItems(items, chips));
    }
}
```

These are the filter classes, based on the filter interface shown above:

```java
class ContourFilter implements Filter{
    @Override
    public boolean isApplicableTo(String itemText) {
        // Place your RegEx check here
    }

    @Override
    public boolean applyTo(ItemULD item, String itemText) {
        String contour = item.getContour();
        return contour.contains(itemText);
    }   
}

class NumFilter implements Filter{
    @Override
    public boolean isApplicableTo(String itemText) {
        if (itemText == null) {
            return false;
        }
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(itemText);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean applyTo(ItemULD item, String itemText) {
        String num = String.valueOf(item.getNumULD());
        return num.contains(itemText);
    }   
}
```

The filters class could look like this:

```java
class Filters{
    private final List<Filter> filtersList;

    public Filters(Filter... filters) {
        this.filtersList = Arrays.asList(filters);
    }
    
    
    public List<ItemULD> applyToItems(List<ItemULD> items, List<Chip> chips) {
        List<ItemULD> filteredItems = new ArrayList<>();
        
        for (ItemULD item : items) {
            if(applyToItem(item, chips)) {
                filteredItems.add(item);
            }
        }
        
        return filteredItems;
    }
    
    public boolean applyToItem(ItemULD item, List<Chip> chips) {
        boolean result = true;
        
        for (Chip chip : chips) {
            String chipText = chip.getText();
            for (Filter filter : filtersList) {
                if(filter.isApplicableTo(chipText)) {
                    result = result && filter.applyTo(item, chipText);
                }
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

The `Chip` class is only a simplified version:

```java
class Chip{
    private final String text;

    public Chip(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay I'm trying, I created the interface + contour class but, how I should apply the filter on the list of items if I have them in the other class `ItemULD`.  In isApplicableTo I use a Regex to check it but in 'applyTo(String itemText)' should I add applyTo(String itemText, ArrayList<ItemULD>) or how can I apply the filter.. ? 
Thanks

Comment: No, you don‘t modify the list in the interface implementation. You just move the contents of the if clause (the conditional check only) to that class. Your calling code then adds the item to the list - as before.

Comment: I edited the interface (the applyTo() method needs the item). I will try to provide a working code example.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, work like a charm. I was stuck and tired to try so much things :(